# Paste values in Excel without using VBA

Tags: excel-formula, copy-paste

This may not be possible, but I have a spreadsheet that generates silly writing prompts for kids. I want to make it easy for my users (kids and their parents) to be able to copy and paste prompts they like onto a separate tab for Saved Prompts.

Copying and pasting only pastes the formula, which generates a new prompt regularly. In order to actually save a prompt, the user must paste values.

I created a VBA button that accomplished this, but it can't be used on mobile versions of Excel, which is how many of my users access the file. I'd love to be able to create some way for users to easily copy and paste values, but I can't come up with anything other than VBA.

My alternative is to add text with instructions on how to do it, but that is not straightforward either considering that the instructions will be different depending on whether the user is on Mac, PC, or Mobile...

I have created a VBA button, but it does not work on mobile.

Comment: Why not share a file that has the prompts as text instead of formula? keep the formula version as your own 'Mastersheet'?

Comment: There isn't really a master list, though. The prompts are generated by the formula. I have a list of Adjectives, Subjects, Verbs and Prepositional Phrases, and the formula takes a random item from each list to make a new prompt. So the result is something like | Fashionable | grannies | going for a walk | in the jungle. | There's a nearly infinite number of prompts that could be generated from the combinations.

Comment: Well, you really need a user to actively paste the copied range as value if no VBA is allowed. Maybe refer them to `ctrl+C` `ctrl+alt+V`?

Comment: I think that's going to be the best solution. The kids will get the hang of it pretty quickly, and they'll learn a new keyboard shortcut at the same time.

Comment: Hmm.. can mobiles actually do that? They do have the option to paste as values though, but it's not as easy as on a regular pc/laptop.

Comment: It's not as simple on Mobile, but it can be done. I'm adding instructions for both mobile and desktop. I don't have access to a non-iPad tablet, so I'm just hoping the process is essentially the same for all tablets.